# How do I load a typelib to parse it in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, com, typelib

In unmanaged code I can use `LoadTypeLib()` to obtain an `ITypeLib*` pointer and use that to look into the typelib to find what interfaces it contains.

There is `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.ITypeLib` interface in C# but I can't find an equivalent to `LoadTypeLib()` function.

How do I load a typelib and obtain an `ITypeLib` reference in C#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Copied straight from System.Design.NativeMethods, Reflector is useful:

```
[DllImport("oleaut32.dll", PreserveSig=false)]
public static extern ITypeLib LoadTypeLib([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string typelib);
```

Comment: So the answer boils down to "PInvoke LoadTypeLib()" doesn't it?