# Is there a way to view COM entries by traversing a TLB file in .NET?

Tags: typelib, registration-free-com

I'm converting an application to use registration free COM. There are a few 3rd party COM dll's that would normally have regsvr32 called on them. I tested that I can create objects from these 3rd party dlls by making a side-by-side manifest.

I used the OLE/COM viewer built into Windows to get this information. However I would like to make a program that could do this for me manually, as these 3rd party libraries have lots of classes I need to put in the manifest.

Does anyone know of a way to programatically traverse a type library?

Comment: It is not very clear why you want to do this the hard way.  Just set Isolated = True in the Properties window for the reference and it is all automagic from there.  Re-inventing this feature, well, ouch.  Keep in mind that the type library is not enough, you don't know anything about the proxy/stub for the component.  Read the type library with LoadTypeLib().

Comment: I'm not doing this from a .NET project

Comment: Not much point in using the [c#] and [.net] tags then, is there?  Still the easiest way to generate the .manifest file you want.

Comment: Yeah, I see why it's confusing. I want to generate the manifest using .NET code if I can... but my assignment is to get lots of COM projects (both native and managed) to talk to each other. There are lots of nuances, and for me doing it the old fashioned way helps me learn the right way to do it instead of trying to troubleshoot the auto-magic. I've got 50+ pages of Microsoft documentation on my desk on assembly manifests, isolated apps, activation of .NET vs Managed COM components, etc. Thanks for the LoadTypeLib() tip though, I think that's going to be a huge help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I load a typelib to parse it in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529798/how-do-i-load-a-typelib-to-parse-it-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took Hans' advice and used LoadTypeLib.

For anyone looking for example code, this should be a great starting point.
I wrote it this morning and was able to get xml that I needed.

Forgive me for not releasing the objects! I don't have time to fully flesh out the rest of this answer right now. Edits are welcome.

```
    [DllImport("oleaut32.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
    public static extern ITypeLib LoadTypeLib([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string typelib);

    public static void ParseTypeLib(string filePath)
    {

        string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
        ITypeLib typeLib = LoadTypeLib(filePath);

        int count = typeLib.GetTypeInfoCount();
        IntPtr ipLibAtt = IntPtr.Zero;
        typeLib.GetLibAttr(out ipLibAtt);

        var typeLibAttr = (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.TYPELIBATTR)
            Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipLibAtt, typeof(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.TYPELIBATTR));
        Guid tlbId = typeLibAttr.guid;

        for(int i=0; i< count; i++)
        {
            ITypeInfo typeInfo = null;
            typeLib.GetTypeInfo(i, out typeInfo);

            //figure out what guids, typekind, and names of the thing we're dealing with
            IntPtr ipTypeAttr = IntPtr.Zero;
            typeInfo.GetTypeAttr(out ipTypeAttr);

            //unmarshal the pointer into a structure into something we can read
            var typeattr = (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.TYPEATTR)
                Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipTypeAttr, typeof(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.TYPEATTR));

            System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.TYPEKIND typeKind = typeattr.typekind;
            Guid typeId = typeattr.guid;

            //get the name of the type
            string strName, strDocString, strHelpFile;
            int dwHelpContext;
            typeLib.GetDocumentation(i, out strName, out strDocString, out dwHelpContext, out strHelpFile);


            if (typeKind == System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.TYPEKIND.TKIND_COCLASS)
            {
                string xmlComClassFormat = "<comClass clsid=\"{0}\" tlbid=\"{1}\" description=\"{2}\" progid=\"{3}.{4}\"></comClass>";
                string comClassXml = String.Format(xmlComClassFormat, 
                    typeId.ToString("B").ToUpper(),
                    tlbId.ToString("B").ToUpper(),
                    strDocString,
                    fileNameOnly, strName
                    );
                //Debug.WriteLine(comClassXml);
            }
            else if(typeKind == System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.TYPEKIND.TKIND_INTERFACE)
            {
                string xmlProxyStubFormat = "<comInterfaceExternalProxyStub name=\"{0}\" iid=\"{1}\" tlbid=\"{2}\" proxyStubClsid32=\"{3}\"></comInterfaceExternalProxyStub>";
                string proxyStubXml = String.Format(xmlProxyStubFormat,
                    strName,
                    typeId.ToString("B").ToUpper(),
                    tlbId.ToString("B").ToUpper(),
                    "{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
                );
                //Debug.WriteLine(proxyStubXml);
            }

        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - although this is simple, it's very much appreciated. It's very useful to be able to develop simple command line tools for doing this sort of stuff.

Comment: You're very welcome! Thanks for the up vote.